# Enqueue Scheduled Firebase cloud functions V2

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, scheduled-tasks

My goal is to run the function every day at 9 AM and then reschedule the function accordingly the same day at a random time. However, when trying to reschedule it inside the main scheduled function, it won't run again at a later time.

How can I refactor the logic to ensure the proper scheduling of the rescheduled function?

```
exports.startProcess = onSchedule("every day 09:00", async (event) => {
            const users = await database.getUsers();
        
            for (const user of users) {
                const frequency = user.profile.notifications?.frequency;

    // Re schedule later today    
    let schedule = generateSchedule()
      
            onSchedule(schedule, async (event) => {
                await generateContent(user);
            });
        
            }
        });
        
        function generateSchedule(): string {
            const randomHour = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 9;
            const randomMinute = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60);
            return `${randomMinute} ${randomHour} * * *`;
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  Are you observing some specific behavior you want to change? There is nothing in here that looks like "recursion" to me.

Comment: Maybe there’s no problem, I’m asking to avoid multiples calls in parallel in a period of time if it’s not a good practice . Will it run everyday and in parallel wait for the re scheduled function to execute (e.g next week)  before finishing the main function? Or it will finish and re run at the scheduled time? @DougStevenson

Comment: If that's your question, then please edit the post to reflect your actual concern here so there can be a formal answer that addresses the post.  What you're describing is not called "recursion". As your post stands right now, it's trying to address a concern that isn't proven to exist. It needs to show observations along with steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DougStevenson Here you go, I refactored the question to the core problem I have

Comment: You can't call `onSchedule` from within `onSchedule`. That just won't work. `onSchedule` just builds a definition of a job and returns an object that Cloud Functions will use later to invoke your handler function (the second argument you pass to `onSchedule`).  It's not possible to reschedule the function at all - it will only execute on the schedule you initially provide.

Comment: Yes, this is what I already noticed, do you have a suggestion for another approach if I need to schedule it every morning and then reschedule in a later time? the ``timeout`` of a scheduled function is ``60 minutes`` so I can't even delay or await it. @DougStevenson

Comment: You can't do this with Cloud Functions. You will need to use a different product, such as Cloud Tasks.

Comment: I think i can Enqueue Scheduled functions in the ``V2``of firebase cloud functions using Cloud tasks as you specified @DougStevenson